# Jump fails in LC3

Tags: subroutine, lc3

I seem to be having a problem with LC3 assembly.

I'm trying to jump to a subroutine, but instead it just goes through to the next command.

I've tried:

```
LD R0, Subpgm
JSRR R0
```

and at the bottom, This line to define Subpgm.

```
Subpgm .FILL x4000
```

I expected this to jump to `PC x4000`, but instead the PC is just incremented by the normal 1.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Comment: I figured this out. The simulator I was using has a next and a skip command. One of them doesn't show the JSRR working, it just processes and goes to the return command. The other jumps correctly and shows the working of the subroutine.
Thanks for answering!

Answer (score 1):

You're using the JSRR command correctly, I would have to see the rest of your code to understand what's causing the error.